# When attempting to Verify my CouchDB installation I get the error "Error: could not resolve http://any:5984/verifytestdb/"

Tags: docker, couchdb

When I install CouchDB and use the GUI and run verify.

I get the error

```
Error: could not resolve http://any:5984/verifytestdb/
```

And Replication status get's an X saying I can't replicate. Any suggestion on how to fix this problem.

It's running in a Docker Container and the Ports says

```
4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp
```

The GUI should same it works an not show an Error.

Feel like a port might be blocked in 5986 required for replication.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Config setting on on the CouchDB GUI

Go to **httpd**

Then select **bind_address**

And and change the value from "Any" to "bind_address"

Run the test again and it should work.

Comment: I followed your instructions and it failed when I changed "Any" to "bind_address"
I then tried "0.0.0.0" in place of "Any" and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

for me what works is adding to couchdb config or change in UI

```
[httpd]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

tested with verify and

```
curl -vX POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate      -d '{"source":"albums","target":"albums-replica","create_target":true}'      -H "Content-Type: application/json"

{"ok":true,"session_id":"9ab3e4f1a9cae16df05b32866088510c","source_last_seq":"6-g1AAAAILeJyNkU0OgjAQRqto1IVn0CMA_YGu5CZKOzVIsF2o......
```

with docker exposing only port

```
services:
  couchdb:
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
```