# Error: could not resolve http://any:5984/verifytestdb/ in CouchDB Docker container

Tags: docker, couchdb

I'm starting to learn CouchDB by reading through the [user guide](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/index.html) and following along with a Docker container run off the [official CouchDB image](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb) (using tag `latest`, CouchDB 2.3.1). I'm using one container, running locally. configured as a single node via the Fauxton Setup page using default options (e.g. `bind address` set to `0.0.0.0`).

When I run Fauxton's Verify Installation tool, the first 5 checks pass, but the replication check fails with message:

```
Error: could not resolve http://any:5984/verifytestdb/
```

Similarly, when I try to replicate a sample database to another database on the same node, it fails:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5984/_all_dbs
["_global_changes","_replicator","_users","albums","albums-replica"]

$ curl http://localhost:5984/_replicate \
-d '{"source": "albums", "target": "albums-replica"}' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
{"error":"nxdomain","reason":"could not resolve http://any:5984/albums/"}
```

I notice in both cases the errors say `any` rather than `0.0.0.0`, but I don't know if that's significant.

I have also tried running a new container via `docker run --name loveseat -p 5984:5984 -d couchdb:latest`, completing Fauxton setup, and immediately clicking Verify Install in Fauxton, and I observe the same error.

Any ideas what's wrong / what I'm missing?

**Update**

I have tried the same procedure on the following Docker image tags:

- `latest`
- `2.3.1`
- `2.3`
- `2.3.0`
- `2`

All with the same result.

Comment: Where did the `any` in the URL come from?

Comment: I'm wondering that as well. I know the default `bind_address` Fauxton displays on its CHTTPD configuration page before completing setup is `any`, but I definitely set it to `0.0.0.0` before running the above code, so that `any` confuses me, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Fauxton in `Config` -> `Main config` switch your `httpd` `bind_address` from `any` to `0.0.0.0`

I think this is a repeat of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334950/when-attempting-to-verify-my-couchdb-installation-i-get-the-error-error-could)

Part of the `local.ini` file I use is below.

```
[chttpd]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
port = 5984
; When this option is set to true, no requests are allowed from anonymous users. Everyone must be authenticated.
require_valid_user = false

[cluster]
n = 1

[httpd]
enable_cors = true
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Good catch, but I actually checked that question before posting. The instructions crashed the server (`bind_address = bind_address` is nonsense AFAICT, but I realized that a moment after saving the change), and I got to spend a couple hours learning how to locate and fix the incorrect setting in a Docker container that crashed a second after boot. I have confirmed, on both my main container and my fresh-out-of-the-box container, that `bind_address` is set to `0.0.0.0`. I omitted all of the above in the question for brevity. (Perhaps I shouldn't have.)

Comment: Really that's strange. I'm developing a CouchDB app and am using a docker container running the latest version of couchdb without issue.

Comment: If you're willing to do a quick check, what happens if you run a fresh container (perhaps on `couchdb:2.3.1`), complete the Fauxton setup for a single node, and immediately run Fauxton's Verify Install?

Comment: "Success! Your couchDB installation is working. Time to Relax."

I have a Dockerfile, local.ini and docker-compose.yml file. Give me 10 minutes and I'll make a git repo. I'm curious if it will work for you.

I don't run the Configure a Single Node and couchdb syncs with pouchdb in my vue app.

Comment: Check out the repo [here](https://github.com/EricCBonet/docker_couchdb)

Comment: Thanks!  Very interesting. That works perfectly for me.

Comment: Ah. The issue was that `httpd` still had `bind_address` set to `any` and I didn't even know that section existed! Setting it to `0.0.0.0` causes the test to pass.